# Change default joomla Backend Language programaticly

Tags: joomla

I need to change the default backend/admin language of an Joomla site programmaticly.
I know how to change in Backend, but in this case it is nessesary to change it in the code.

Do anyone know a solution or has an code snipet on how to change the default admin language?

Comment: This will get a better answer on the [joomla.se] stack exchange site.
Also you should try to explain more what you are doing. Do you mean you don't want to allow users to change their language?

Comment: Thanks for your Idea :-) I've moved to Joomla stack exchange https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/26298/change-default-joomla-backend-language-programaticly